# A math olympiad question: find the radii of three mutually tangent circles included into a surrounding rectangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I saw this question in a book of olympiad maths but I have been puzzled how to do this
[image]

Question : In the figure ABCD is a rectangle, find the radius of all circles

This question is from Pathfinder for Olympiad Mathematics

PS I found this interesting as this shows how  without any advanced concept the simple pythagoras formula can be used to make an olympiad level question.

Comment: What have you tried?  The radius of the left circle is trivial... right?

Comment: Please edit your question to add your thoughts and efforts to solving the problem.

Comment: The left circle's radius is of course 36 but what about the other two

Comment: The big one is easy,  then you may start that of the right down corner

Comment: @PulkitSabharwal: Here are the full detailed explanations to solve your problem. https://www.academia.edu/10798008/Mathematical_Analysis_of_Three_Externally_Touching_Circles_Derivations_of_inscribed_and_circumscribed_radii_for_three_externally_touching_circles_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark the Centers of the Circles $X$ & $Y$ & $Z$ and make the triangle $XYZ$.

Now let the Radii be $x$ & $y$ & $z$. The triangle will have sides $x+y$ & $y+z$ & $z+x$ which are the hypotenuses of 3 right-angled triangles with Sides Parallel to the sides of the given rectangle.

Use Pythagoras Theorem to equate the Hypotenuses in terms of the Sides. Solve these Simultaneous Equations.

You can make it a little easier by using the value of $x$ which is obviously 36.

EG: Consider the lower 2 circles with centers $X$ & $Z$ which make the line $ZX$ with length $z+x$ : It is Part of the right-angled triangle with base $100-x-z$ & height $72-x-z$ ; We can see the right-angled triangle here :

[image: line between the centers of the circles X & Z ; the right-angled triangle with hypotenuse XZ]

With Pythagoras Theorem, this gives us the Equation :

$(100-x-z)^2+(72-x-z)^2=(x+z)^2$

Similarly we have make Equations with $x+y$ & $y+z$ and then Solve these Simultaneous Equations, in general.

In this Particular Case, we can get $x=36$ and plug into the given Equation to get :

$(100-36-z)^2+(72-36-z)^2=(36+z)^2$

We can easily get $z$ now. Leaving $y$ to you.

Comment: i didnt get it , please provide the full solution

Comment: **"Please provide the full solution"**... don't you ask a little too much ?Please **work** on these important hints, and then come back with precise questions.

Comment: sorry for the comment

Comment: What the other users are rightly telling you is that, all these hints in the comments (and this answer) are enough to solve your Q, but you must work on the Solution; I will add a bit more hints !

Comment: @PulkitSabharwal: Follow this link to find the formula and get the detailed solution to your question. https://www.academia.edu/10798008/Mathematical_Analysis_of_Three_Externally_Touching_Circles_Derivations_of_inscribed_and_circumscribed_radii_for_three_externally_touching_circles_

Comment: Z=16  X= 36 Y =81/4 ( 20.25)

Comment: The figure is wrong. Maybe that causes the problem. The circle on the right at the top is larger than the circle right below. The top circle reaches outside the rectangle. I think a picture should never represent an impossible solution.

Comment: Nice Catch ! I did not complete the Solution , leaving it after giving hints to OP , but when I solve it , I see that not just the figure , the Problem itself is wrong. The top circle reaching outside is not the only Issue. The bottom circle will not go beyond half the left circle ! @PaulvdVeen